# Improve performance of waiting mutexes on different physical processors

Tags: multithreading, winapi, synchronization

When I experimented with different variants of mutexes, finally I came to 2 fastest primitives.

One is InterlockedExchange-based (well-known method)

```
Access:
  while InterlockedExchange(AccessFlag, 1) <> 0 do
Release:
  InterlockedExchange(AccessFlag, 0)
```

Another one is event-based.

```
Init:
  Event = CreateEvent(Null, false, true, Null);
Access:
  WaitForSingleObject(Event, INFINITE)
Release:
  SetEvent(Event)
```

InterlockedExchanged-based was fastest always, but it suffered from not-sleeping in case of failure. On the other side it worked greatly either on single physical processor (core) or on multiple cores. Although small benefit of single core test was that there were no failures if I added Sleep(0) inside the loop.

Event-based is great in waiting while sleeping, but when I measured the performance, I noticed that several threads working with this type of mutex perform faster if they reside on the single physical processor (SetThreadAffinityMask called with identical values or testing on a single-core computer) than on different processors. Depending on the type of processor, this varied from x4 (iCore 5) to x8 (Xeon).

Some statistics from Xeon

3 threads, each increases a variable by 10 (10,000,000 steps) accessing it with a mutex at each increase.

- Multi-processor, InterlockedExcchange-based

  344 msec / Per Ms: 87,209
  / Failures in while loop: 2,487,376 (8% of total steps from 3
  threads, Sleep(0) exists but probably useless with multi-processor threads)
- Multi-processor, Event-based

  6187 msec / Per Ms: 4,848
- Single processor, InterlockedExcchange-based

  281 msec / Per Ms:
  106,761 / Failures in while loop: 0 (Sleep(0) inside the loop);
- Single processor, Event-based

  765 msec / Per Ms: 39,215

I assume that real inter-core synchronization has some penalty. But I would like to "marry" the perfect performance of the InterlockedExchange method with the correctness ("sleep if you don't work") of the event-based approach. Is this possible?

Comment: Something has to be wrong with the way you measured, because spinning on `InterlockedExchange` provides the worst performance of any mechanism that isn't intentionally sabotaged. Each spin locks the cache line, so you saturate the bus with inter-CPU traffic, slowing cores trying to do useful work (such as the one that will ultimately release the lock!) to a crawl. And when you finally do get the lock, you take the mother of all mispredicted branches and basically have to start the pipelines from scratch. I'm not sure how you're measuring, but I suspect its horribly unrealistic.

Comment: @David_Schwartz, hmm, how can it be worst if the call itself (InterlockedExchange) takes about 8 native assembly instructions in Windows (including native "lock cmpxchg")

Comment: Because one of those native assembly instructions unconditionally locks the cache line every other core trying to acquire that same lock is also trying to lock -- and it does so for no reason. The cores could perfectly well share the cache line until the lock is released. That is like the worst thing you could possibly do -- while the lock is held, all the cores trying to compete for the lock ping-pong the cache line and saturate the bus that the core that holds the lock is trying to use to finish its real work so it can release the lock.

Comment: When you teach people how to write synchronization primitives, you show this first as the naive "brain dead" implementation and then you start improving on it. The first improvement is to avoid locking the cache line if the exchange is unlikely to succeed. The second is to avoid the mispredicted branch when you acquire the lock. Bluntly, if you think that's a sensible synchronization primitive, you literally don't know the first thing about how to write synchronization primitives. That's where people are before they learn anything about how to do it properly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I *had* to +1 the first comment just for the vernacular of "mother of all mispredicted branches.." I had to jot that down for future usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one common way of doing this is to spin on the CAS step for only a limited number of tries.  If your condition does not become true in a timely fashion, then you go through the overhead of the "more expensive" event based solution.

Comment: This might work, but the problem is that the working thread should detect that someone waits with another method. Probably another event intended just for signaling of method switching and not waiting

Comment: I tried to implement something like this and this method improved the performance. The working thread always sets the event and waiting one does waiting after a couple of failures. This exclusion of unconditional waiting is probably shows that waiting for multi-processor configuration is the main reason behind slowing.